# Jersey error deserializing ArrayList from JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, jersey, jackson

Here is the important information. Using Jersey 1.6. There is no issue serializing this same type of list going to the front end, and lists of different types aren't causing problems elsewhere in the application going back and forth, so I think the problem is with the bean itself. I've tried this without the additional path param, I'm following all of the bean conventions, the data looks fine before ajax... really have no clue where my problem is. No information is really given other than it's an NPE.

Bean

```
public class TheBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String beanId;
private String name;
private String beanType;
private Boolean group;

public TheBean(){}

public TheBean(String beanId, String name, String beanType, boolean isGroup) {
    super();
    this.beanId = beanId;
    this.name = name;
    this.beanType = beanType;
    this.group = isGroup;
}


public String getBeanId() {
    return beanId;
}
public void setBeanId(String beanId) {
    this.beanId = beanId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getBeanType() {
    return beanType;
}
public void setBeanType(String beanType) {
    this.beanType = beanType;
}
public boolean isGroup() {
    return group;
}
public void setGroup(boolean group) {
    this.group = group;
}
}
```

The web service

```
@POST
@Path("/update/{parentId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateTheBeanList(ArrayList<TheBean> routeList, @PathParam("parentId") String parentId){
    //code
}
```

The client side code

```
var beanListArray = beanListTable.fnGetData();//looks good here
var json = JSON.stringify(beanListArray);//and here

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'text',
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/rest/beanList/update/' + parentId, //looks good here
});
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findAdapter(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:1058)
at org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findDeserializer(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:644)
at org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findDeserializer(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:74)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector.findDeserializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:634)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findDeserializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1286)
```

The dependencies in question

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: strange, I assume following problems: 1. `@XmlRootElement` is not present on `TheBean`. 2. `List<TheBean> routeList` instead of `ArrayList<TheBean> routeList` BUT I did not get, why you got the `NullPointerException` - maybe a bug, are you able to update the dependencies?

Comment: I don't annotate any of the beans with `@XmlRootElement`, and I use `ArrayList` elsewhere in web services without issue. The only difference is the additional path param, but I've tried without it. It's possibly a bug, I will tinker with the dependencies.

Comment: maybe, but give it a try, annotate TheBean with  @XmlRootElement and change the returntype to List... what happens?

Comment: if this is not changing anything... you could add the maven dependencies to your question... sometimes there are strange things related with specific combinations of deps...

Comment: Yes good idea, OP updated with pom snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case Jackson is using the class `org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` to deserialize/serialize the ArrayList with your POJOs (I assume you configured `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` in your web.xml).

Jackson is looking for an annotation, which is not present. See line 643 in `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java`:

```
Class potentialAdaptee = ((Member)am.getAnnotated()).getDeclaringClass();
```

where `am.getAnnotated()` is `null`.

Because you have not "annotated any of the beans with @XmlRootElement" a simple solution would be to disable the use of `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`. This can be done by registering a custom `ContextResolver` providing an own `ObjectMapper` instance.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class PojoObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public PojoObjectMapperProvider() {
        defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        defaultObjectMapper.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {

        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }
}
```

To register that class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(PojoObjectMapperProvider.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

and if you not use a web.xml:

```
ApplicationAdapter rc = new ApplicationAdapter(new MyApplication());
rc.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyServerFactory.create(BASE_URI, rc);
```

Comment: Works. While I didn't use the exact code, I pulled a similar ContextResolver from another project (that I wrote :/) and I'm in business. Good catch!